# How to avoid redirect loop when using Firebase's authWithOAuthRedirect

Tags: authentication, firebase

I have the following code running, which results in the page continuing to attempt to reload and the user never appearing to be authenticated. It should be noted that this works as expected when using the `authWithOAuthPopup` method.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com");

var existingAuthData = myDataRef.getAuth(); //After the oauth redirect and every subsequent load, this is always null

//register onAuth listener
myDataRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
    //We never get this far as the page continues to attempt to load
    if (authData !== null){
        console.log('logged in now!')
    }       
    else {
        console.log('not logged in yet')
    }
})

if (existingAuthData !== null) {
    console.log('User already logged in');
}
else {
    console.log('getAuth returned nothing - authenticating');
    myDataRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("github", function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
      }
    });
}
```

After authenticating with github the page is redirected back to my custom domain with a hash appended: `#&__firebase_request_key=Qwnn9TtM2fsIHq44vhCcbXbPa0DMPL1N`.

The page then reloads, leaving just the # in the url, before reloading again with the firebase_request_key hash. This continues indefinitely.

Again, it's worth noting that this works as expected if I switch the `authWithOAuthRedirect` method for `authWithOAuthPopup`.

How can I get the redirect method to work the way I'm expecting it to?

Comment: answer by @tgf solves the issue

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the synchronous `ref.getAuth()` to monitor the authentication state when using the `ref.authWithOAuthRedirect`. You have to use the `ref.onAuth(<callback>)` to monitor the authentication state. For example:

```js
    //create your root reference
    var rootRef = new Firebase('https://example.firebaseio.com/');

    // Create a callback which logs the current auth state
    function authDataCallback(authData) {
        if (!authData) {
            console.log(authData);
            rootRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("github", function (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        }
    }

    rootRef.onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and it appeared to be a race condition.  Slightly delaying auth using setTimeout() has helped.

Something like this:

```js
var onAuthCallback = function(authData) {
  if (!authData) {
    rootRef.authWithOAuthRedirect("google", function (error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    });
  }
  else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    rootRef.offAuth(onAuthCallback);
  }
};

// Important: don't request authentication immediately
setTimeout(function() { rootRef.onAuth(onAuthCallback); }, 400);
```

Comment: this solved it no other thing was working, this is weird tho

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in version 2.4 of Firebase. See the [changelog for javascript api](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html).

Try `https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js` or newer.